# Unable to connect to dockerized redis instance from outside docker

Tags: redis, docker, localhost

I have the latest docker installation (without boot2docker) and I am unable to connect to a dockerized redis instance running locally. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**Created the docker, mapped port 6379 to 127.0.0.1:6379**

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379  --name webmonitor-redis -d redis
3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9
```

**docker ps output:**

```
bash-3.2$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
3291541d58ab        redis               "/entrypoint.sh redis"   14 seconds ago      Up 6 seconds        127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp   webmonitor-redis
```

**Tried connecting from outside container (but the same host where container is running), connection failed:**

```
bash-3.2$ ./src/redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected> exit
```

**It works if I try to connect from another container though..**

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -it --link webmonitor-redis:redis --rm redis sh -c 'exec redis-cli -h "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR" -p "$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"'
172.17.0.8:6379>
```

**Here's the docker inspect for the container:**

```
bash-3.2$ docker inspect 3291541d58ab
[
{
    "Id": "3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9",
    "Created": "2015-10-03T15:48:17.818355794Z",
    "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "redis-server"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 7769,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2015-10-03T15:48:17.954436198Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "2f2578ff984f013c9a5d6cbb6fe061ed3f73a17380a4c9b53b76d4b8da3eda7d",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "EndpointID": "b787e46d1219f36d4f1b1ea35c5f750f7174221137fb01889a26a3bc1e1c6aee",
        "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.8",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:08",
        "NetworkID": "30176c9c7c14a6a052af784014832a0c52b5966089d7bcfe535041569e6bb1c9",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": {
            "6379/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                    "HostPort": "6379"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/3291541d58ab",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
    },
    "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9/3291541d58ab16c362f9e0cd7017d179c0bc9aef3a1323e79f1e1ca075e171c9-json.log",
    "Name": "/webmonitor-redis",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {
            "6379/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                    "HostPort": "6379"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "aufs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "643a80cbd7a50cfd481acc48721b34030c8ce55ba64ac3bc161d5b330c9374d2",
            "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/643a80cbd7a50cfd481acc48721b34030c8ce55ba64ac3bc161d5b330c9374d2/_data",
            "Destination": "/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "3291541d58ab",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "6379/tcp": {}
        },
        "PublishService": "",
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "REDIS_VERSION=3.0.3",
            "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.3.tar.gz",
            "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA1=0e2d7707327986ae652df717059354b358b83358"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "redis-server"
        ],
        "Image": "redis",
        "Volumes": {
            "/data": {}
        },
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "WorkingDir": "/data",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "NetworkDisabled": false,
        "MacAddress": "",
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    }
}
]
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Note: The host is Mac OS X

Answer (score 18):

make sure the port 6379 on the host is forwarded to port 6379 on docker.
use `-p 6379:6379` to fixed the problem:

```
docker run -d --name redisDev -p 6379:6379 redis
```

Answer (score 5):

The VM has it's own IP 192.168.99.100 so I was able to connect by binding to 192.168.99.100:6379:6379 and then connecting as below.

```
0c4de9a25467:redis-stable electron$ ./src/redis-cli -h 192.168.99.100
192.168.99.100:6379>
```

Comment: How did you find VM's IP?

Comment: @jaycode typically you can find the IP via `docker-machine ip default`
or see the full list with `docker-machine ls`

Answer (score -3):

`docker run -p 6379:6379 -host 0.0.0.0 --name webmonitor-redis -d redis`